# Error when installing pip. EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal

Tags: python, pip, eof, mousewheel

I'm trying to install pip to my mac and keep running into a String literal error.

I run this to create the file from the get-pip website:

> curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py > get_pip.py

But when I run the python file I get the error:

> ```
>    File "get-pip.py", line 9947
>    tE8
>      ^
>    SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal
> ```

Comment: Hmm, that is odd. Have you considered installing via brew?

Comment: Sounds like you got an incomplete download -- try downloading `get-pip.py` again?

Comment: Check whether the script you downloaded is complete: `python -m py_compile get-pip.py`